# How to ignore parsing errors due to wrong encoding in LibXML?

Tags: xml, perl, parsing, encoding, utf-8

I have to parse XML (in [`XML::LibXML`](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::LibXML0)) that is not marked with the correct encoding. Specifically, it contains a German `ü` Umlaut (there may be others), but has no `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1" ?>` or the like. When I try to parse this with LibXML using this line:

```
my $smDOM = $PRSR->load_xml(location => $smfile, no_blanks => 1)
```

I get the error `parser error : Input is not proper UTF-8, indicate encoding !`.

I also tried it with

```
my $smDOM = $PRSR->load_xml(location => $smfile, no_blanks => 1, encoding=> "iso-8859-1");
```

which results in the same error.

- Is there a way to disable UTF-8 as the default encoding?
- Or to disregard encoding errors while parsing?
- Or to specify a different encoding at the time the parser is called or created?
- And by the way, I don't understand why a simple German umlaut is not proper UTF-8?

Comment: Re "I don't understand why a simple German umlaut is not proper UTF-8?" You have byte `FC` according to what you said (the iso-8859-1 encoding of "ü"). `FC` is not valid UTF-8. The UTF-8 encoding of "ü" is bytes `C3 BC`.

Answer (score 4):

What you have there is not XML or HTML, the two formats supported by XML::LibXML.

The `encoding` argument is strictly for functions who name match `/html/` since the encoding of HTML documents is not always found in HTML documents. On the other hand, the encoding of an XML document *must* be specified in the document if it's not UTF-8.

So you convert what you have into proper XML. You could add the encoding declaration to the XML document, or you could convert its encoding to UTF-8.

```
use Encode qw( from_to );
from_to($xml, "iso-8859-1", "UTF-8");
```

Comment: Well, it is XML, it's just not correct XML ;). But I know what you mean. Your solution seems to work nicely, btw.

Comment: @jackthehipster, It doesn't match the definition of an XML document. potayto, potahto.